# make a New Binary Expression List like ([A or B] AND C) in RemObjects

Tags: remobjects, dataabstract

I am trying to build a NewBinaryExpressionList but with this condition:

```
((A OR B) AND C)
```

I think this is a NewBinaryExpressionList within another, but it's not currently working for me.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me more like a simple nested **NewBinaryExpression**, rather than a list:

```
NewBinaryExpression(NewBinaryExpression('A', dboOr, 'B'), dboAnd, 'C');
```